# Removing difficult engine bolts

Tags: engine, vauxhall, stuck-bolt

Currenly trying to remove part of the engine mount off my Vauxhall Astra to get to the thermostat and I've hit a stumbling block by two VERY tight screws that are almost impossible to get a wrench on to.

Does anyone have any tips/tricks that might help in removing these? I really don't care what happens to the bolts, and maybe even the engine mount, but hopefully keep away from damaging engine itself.. Here are a few pictures that show the bolts in question if it helps.

They appear to be T14 in size.

[image: Bolt 2]
[image: Bolt]
[Third picture if necessary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtTqc.jpg)

Comment: Why can't you use a socket? They make them in reverse Torx just for that purpose.

Comment: Because the wheel surround is very close to this side of the engine so it doesn't fit. Edit: the normal socket fits on but it gets stuck on other components, with an extension it doesnt fit

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at the wrong bolts then, or it isn't obvious in the pictures. What are the details on the vehicle itself? Make/model/year?

Comment: Appologies, @Paulster2 .. basically in the two pictures visible its the two very shiny bolts, they're within the timing belt surround which is slightly visible in the pictures which hinders the turning of a socket which means we need an extension to even attempt turning them but none fit due to surrounding components... The Car is a 2003 Vauxhal Astra (1.6 engine).

Comment: I'm sorry, it looks from the picture that a 3/8ths ratchet with the correct socket would fit. Put a cheater on it for extra torque. Wish I was there, could help you in a flash.

Comment: Would you have any tips on how to get difficult bolts off in general? i.e tight, sheared, foobar'ed

Comment: In your case, I would suggest two things you might try. You may be able to come in from the side, but you'd have to jack the car up and take the wheel off on that side. Then remove the inner fender well pieces, which may gain you access. The other thing you could try is disconnecting the motor mount (on the body side) and jacking the engine itself up some. Put a piece of wood between the jack and the oil pan and be careful. In both cases, ensure your parking brake is on. You could try welding the T14 socket to a 5-6mm strip of metal, while making the end long enough to break it loose.

Comment: If the bolts are still stuck after getting a tool to them, you could try something like [Loctite Freeze & Release](http://www.henkelna.com/loctite-freeze-release-7008.htm) to un-stick and lubricate them, or try heating them up with a torch and cooling them down quickly with water to shock them loose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

obviously you tried penetrating oil.Try doing bolts up;may serve to crack any rust or
paint.Failing that place a drift in centre of bolt and hit with a hammer to serve same
purpose.Worst case scenario heat with an oxy torch that will expand then contract bolt
making removal a cinch. CAUTION-be very aware of fuel leaks and remove battery from
near proximity

Comment: In the end, I used penetrating oil which did manage to get me some leverage in removing one of the bolts.. upon doing so I found that someone had used a strong sealant to actually glue the bolt in place.. which is why neither would move. Ended up selling the car for scrap value (with explanation as to why) since the one bolt would not budge